# What should I do if the space in a static UITableView is too small?

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin, interface-builder

I'm currently working in Xamarin with the iOS Designer. I set up my static content of the `UITableViewController`. Now I want to add another static cell but the screen is too small (the content height would be greater than the screen height). There is no room for this.

What can I do? Is this the same for Interface Builder?

**Edit:**

Now I was able to place a cell by dragging it on the `UITableView`. I can see it in the inspector but I'm not able to place a label on it. So the only solution would be to set everything up in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, iOS Designer and Interface builder use either iPhone or iPad frame sizes. You can change this to get the free size. Then you can simply resize the frame by dragging its bounds or setting the values in corresponding input fields.

Comment: I selected the `UITableViewController` and changed `Size` to `Freeform` under *Simulated Metrics* (all in the **Widget** area). Under the **Layout** area I set the `Simulated Size` to `Freeform` and I set a `Width` (320) and `Height` (1000).